# Provide null value for 3-column query result, where inner join may return no result

Tags: sql-server

My objective is to get a table of inventory counts, of many parts. The resultant table will have the part name, the part location, and the count. I have four tables:

- Inventory - lists all inventory id       partType_id
- PartTypes - the types of parts that we may have in inventory id       partName
- Part_Location - association between a part type and where it's stored Location_id      partType_id
- Location - a list of all locations for parts id       nanme

The problem I'm encountering with my query is the subset of parts I'm testing with do not have a location, so the query is returning no results. I would like to provide "NULL" for a location of any part where a location isn't found. I saw where you could use a nested SELECT to return null, but the INNER JOINS confuse the simple example I saw.

Here's my current SQL Server query:

```
SELECT PT.partName AS part_name, L.name AS part_location, COUNT(I.id) AS part_count
FROM Location L
INNER JOIN Part_Location PL ON PL.Location_id = L.id
INNER JOIN PartTypes PT ON PT.id = PL.partType_id
INNER JOIN Inventory I ON I.partType_id = PT.id
GROUP BY L.name, PT.partName
```

What I'd like to see for a result is:

```
part_name        part_location     part_count part-1   
null              100 part-2               null              15
```

etc.

Comment: If a part might not have a location, why not use a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: We need some sample data with matching expected results in order to properly understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to bring in tables which might not have matching records. In this case, that also means listing a different table first.

```sql
SELECT PT.partName AS part_name, L.name AS part_location, COUNT(I.id) AS part_count
FROM PartTypes PT 
INNER JOIN Part_Location PL ON PL.partType_id = PT.id
LEFT JOIN Location L ON L.id = PL.Location_id
INNER JOIN Inventory I ON I.partType_id = PT.id
GROUP BY L.name, PT.partName
```

Comment: I may have omitted a detail regarding no match at all in the Part_Location table. I changed INNER JOIN Part_Location to LEFT JOIN Part_Location and got the results I was looking for. Thanks!